# Vue component in blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to use [this](http://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/) in my Blade view. I have `.vue` file and the following code in JS:

```
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

export default {
  components: {
    Multiselect
  },
  data () {
    return {
      value: '',
      options: ['Select option', 'options', 'selected', 'mulitple', 'label', 'searchable', 'clearOnSelect', 'hideSelected', 'maxHeight', 'allowEmpty', 'showLabels', 'onChange', 'touched']
    }
  }
}
```

When I add the component in Blade like this:

```
<div>
   <label class="typo__label">Single select</label>
   <multiselect v-model="value" :options="options" :searchable="false" :close-on-select="false" :show-labels="false" placeholder="Pick a value"></multiselect>
   <pre class="language-json"><code>@{{value}}</code></pre>
</div>
```

The select doesn't work, it only shows `{{value}}` string. ¿Any ideas?

Comment: what is the given error in the console?

Comment: No errors, apparently all works fine.

Comment: try to remove `@` sign

Comment: If I remove @ blade not recognize {{value}}

Comment: i would say to create a custom component for this

Comment: ¿Component? The component is "multiselect" and i add this in view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the parent component to the HTML too, so if you have main `app.js` it should look like below.

**// mycomponent.js**

```js
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

export default {
  components: {
    Multiselect
  },
  data () {
    return {
      value: '',
      options: ['Select option', 'options', 'selected', 'mulitple', 'label', 'searchable', 'clearOnSelect', 'hideSelected', 'maxHeight', 'allowEmpty', 'showLabels', 'onChange', 'touched']
    }
  }
}
```

**// app.js**

```js
var MyComponent = require('./mycomponent');

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    MyComponent
  }
});
```

**// index.blade.php**

```blade
    <div id="app">
      <my-component inline-template>
        <div>
          <label class="typo__label">Single select</label>
             <multiselect v-model="value" :options="options" :searchable="false" :close-on-select="false" :show-labels="false" placeholder="Pick a value"></multiselect>
           <pre class="language-json"><code>@{{value}}</code></pre>
        </div>
      </my-component>
    </div>
```

`my-component` context in the HTML knows and tracks the value.

**Here is a fiddle so you can see it in action**

```js
const Multiselect = VueMultiselect.Multiselect;

var MyComponent = {
  components: {
    Multiselect
  },
  data() {
      return {
      value: '',
      options: ['Select option', 'options', 'selected', 'mulitple', 'label', 'searchable', 'clearOnSelect', 'hideSelected', 'maxHeight', 'allowEmpty', 'showLabels', 'onChange', 'touched']
    }
  }
};
    
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    MyComponent
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.0-beta.14/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.0-beta.14"></script>
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component inline-template>
    <div>
      <label class="typo__label">Single select</label>
      <multiselect v-model="value" :options="options" :searchable="false" :close-on-select="false" :show-labels="false" placeholder="Pick a value"></multiselect>
      <pre class="language-json"><code>{{value}}</code></pre>
    </div>
  </my-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need add in your blade:

```
  <div id="app">
    <your component/>
       your @{{values}} no need to use @
  </div>
```