# How to use vue.js component in laravel blade?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I registered component in my app.js like this:

```
Vue.component('navbar', require('./components/Navbar.vue'));
```

Now I want to import that component:

```
<template>
<nav class="navbar">CODE HERE</nav>
</template>
```

Into my blade.php file:

```
<body class="">
    <div id="app">
        <div class="">
        <navbar></navbar> <-- here!
        @yield('content')
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Try to get help from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43224985/7844349

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In **app.js**

```
import navbar from './components/Navbar.vue';
Vue.component('navbar', require('./components/Navbar.vue'));

var app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   components: {
       'navbar': require('./components/Navbar.vue'),
   }
});
```

In your **blade**:

```
<body class="">
<div id="app">
    <div class="">
       <navbar></navbar>
       @yield('content')
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unknown custom element: <navbar> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Comment: Use `import navbar from './components/Navbar.vue';` before `Vue.component` statement

Comment: Have you used `export default { }` for app.js??

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: now error here 'navbar': require('./components/Navbar.vue');

Comment: What error you get? Have you `Navbar.vue` in `components` directory?? And give proper path of that file there!

Comment: Another question yet :)
If i have {{message}} variable in navbar and I use it in every page, how to return some mesage to this variable?

Comment: Please post another question for it and accept & upvote this answer!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072623/how-to-return-some-message-to-another-component-in-vue-js

Comment: @Hiren Gohel Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49664451/how-can-i-add-condition-on-vue-component-that-is-loaded-from-the-view-blade-lara

Answer (score 8):

It's an old thread, but: don't forget to run `npm run dev` to compile the app.js

Answer (score 0):

In app.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from './layouts/app.vue';
createApp(App).mount("#first");
```

In your blade:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div id="home"></div>
     @vite('resources/js/app.js')
@endsection
```

In your app.js :

```
<template>
    
    
        <div class="log-form">
  <h2>Login to your account</h2>
  <form >
    <input type="text" title="username" placeholder="username" />
    <input type="password" title="username" placeholder="password" />
    <button type="submit"  class="btn">Login</button>
    <a class="forgot" href="/home">Forgot Username?</a>
  </form>
</div>
   
</template>
```