# Laravel/Vue Component Registration and Vue Instantiation

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I am a new VueJs developer and there is something I can’t seem to get my head around: **Using multiple single page components in the app.js file.**

These are the questions I’m having trouble answering:

1. Am I supposed to register ALL of my top-level (parent) components in the Vue Instance in the app.js file?

```
// App.js
import Component1 from './component/C1.vue';
import Component2 from './component/C2.vue';


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {All Top Level components here?} 
});
```

2. If I need another Vue instance in one of my blade.php files. Where do I instantiate it? Is it best practice to only instantiate Vue once (in the el: #app in app.js) – this doesn’t seem right to me, but I’m new so what do I know.
3. How should I separate my Vue code from my Laravel Code in the main file? (create a separate section?)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <!-- App.js -->
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
<div id="app">

    @yield('content')

</div>

<div id="app2">

<!-- Where can I instantiate this?--> (Question 2)

</div>
</body>

    @yield('vueScripts') <-- (Question 3)

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. You should register all your Vue Component that you will be using inside a blade file.

On the resource folder at the app.js 
`Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);` if you are just using a component on a single parent component you dont need to register the component globally you just register it in the parent component file like so

```
//On Parent Component file
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue' //import child component

 export default 
{ components: { ChildComponent } // child component registration
,
```

Q2. One Vue instance is enough

Q3. You dont need a vuescript if you are already using a vue component vue scripts should go in the vue component file

Comment: **Q1.** 
Do you have an example of how this is done? I was able to find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070616/how-to-use-vue-js-component-in-laravel-blade/46070797
But this is still registering it in the app.js file not the blade.php file

**Q2.** When you say one Vue instance is enough, do you mean per file or for the ENTIRE application? This would be the one instantiation of el:#app in the app.js file correct?

**Q3.** Question for this may be tied to your answer for Q2

Comment: **Q1** On the resource folder at the app.js
`Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);`

if you are just using a component on a single parent component you dont need to register the component globally you just register it in the parent component file like so
`import ComponentA from './ComponentA.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    ComponentA
  },`
 

**Q2** One per entire application the one that's in the app.js file is enough