# How to Use router-link Element in Laravel's Blade

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, router

link tag in blade. I can use it in vue like this;

app.vue;

```
<router-link to="/"><a class="nav-link">Home</a></router-link>
```

When I want to use in blade like this; 
home.blade.php;

```
<router-link to="/"><a class="nav-link">Home</a></router-link>
```

Route is not working. What can I do?

Comment: Make sure the router-link element is inside of your v-app element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use vue.js component in laravel blade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070616/how-to-use-vue-js-component-in-laravel-blade)

Comment: <router-link to="/"><a>HOME<router-link> should work, just verify your root entry div  <div id="app"> that you mention in your app.js

Answer (score -1):

You can use normal a tag ,  for the href you can pass link or route name for example

```
<a href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a>
```