# Why my web page is blank in laravel vue app?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

I have installed vue in laravel and then run command **npm run watch** with php artisan serve. But when loading the page nothing appears.
Whats the problem ? There is no error.

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import store from './store'
import './index.css'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).use(store).mount('#app')
```

**App.vue**

```
<script setup>
// This starter template is using Vue 3 <script setup> SFCs
// Check out https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#script-setup
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
export default{
  components:{
    HelloWorld,
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
    <HelloWorld msg="Hello Vue 3 + Vite" />
  </div>
</template>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

And also included .vue() in webpack.mix.js .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel then you need to add your Vue component to to your app.js file

`Vue.component('app-page', require('./components/App.vue').default);`

Then from a blade file or layout file you can use your Vue component by calling it with

`<app-page></app-page>`

here is another way of doing it [How to use vue.js component in laravel blade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070616/how-to-use-vue-js-component-in-laravel-blade)