# Vue components not loading but router-views loads normally

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, laravel-blade

I'm trying to figure out why on earth I can load my component through router-view but not by calling the component itself.

In my blade file when I write `'<router-view />'`, It loads my **CategoryDropdown** component normally but when I write CategoryDropdown It disappears and I get this console error:

```
'app.js:7307 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: categorydropdown
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
at <App>'
```

Here is the code for my app.js:

```js
require("./bootstrap");

import Alpine from "alpinejs";

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();

import { createApp } from "vue";
import router from "./router";
import CategoryDropdown from "./components/categories/CategoryDropdown";
import vClickOutside from "click-outside-vue3";

createApp({
    components: {
        CategoryDropdown,
    },
})
    .use(router, vClickOutside)
    .mount("#app");
```

Here is the blade file noting that if i simply replaced this  with  it will work:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<header class="max-w-xl mx-auto mt-10 text-center">
    <h1 class="text-4xl">
        <span class="bg-gradient-to-r from-green-300 via-blue-500 to-purple-600 px-2 py-1 rounded-xl text-white">
            Hands On Tech</span>
        blog
    </h1>

    <h2 class="inline-flex mt-2 items-center">
        By Mostafa Said
        <img class="wavingHand" src="/images/wavinghand.png" width="35px" alt="Waving Hand" />
    </h2>

    <p class="text-sm mt-5">
        Come'on in and check out my latest blog posts. I'm sharing whatever on
        my mind and my mind is full of useful stuff for you'all.
    </p>

    <div class="space-y-2 lg:space-y-0 lg:space-x-4 mt-8">
        <!--  Category -->
        <div class="override relative lg:inline-flex items-center bg-blue-100 rounded-xl">


            <CategoryDropdown />

            <!-- This works  -->
            <!-- <router-view /> -->

        </div>

        <!-- Search -->
        <div class="override flex lg:inline-flex items-center bg-blue-50 rounded-xl px-3 py-2">
            <form method="GET" action="#">
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Looking for something?" class="shadow-none focus:shadow-none bg-transparent placeholder-black text-sm border-none outline-hidden" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

This is the layout:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="scroll-smooth">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="High quality Web Development articles" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Hands On Tech Blog" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="High quality Web Development articles" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://" />
    <title>Hands On Tech Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/override.css" />
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</head>
</html>
```

I want to be able to see my component when I call it in blade like this '' instead of using ''

Comment: Can you post the code instead of screenshots? That way we could test and possibly alter the code ourselves

Comment: Good, a lot clearer. But now we need the rest of the code, the blade files, etc. All the code that has to do with this error. Keep in mind that we are blank ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure either. [This might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43224985/757201) though